# HP Probook 6470b BIOS locked

Tags: bios, virtualization

I want to enable Intel's virtualization technology in my BIOS but my BIOS is locked with a password which was setup by the previous owner of the laptop.

Is there any other way to enable Intel VT-X or how do I remove the password?

Comment: "Is there any other way to enable Intel VT-X" nope, not that I've ever seen.  Has to be done in the BIOS (outside of an OS).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the internal battery that is on the motherboard, wait 1 minute, then put it back in, but that would probably require taking most of the laptop apart. That is the only way to remove the password. Otherwise, you would need a new motherboard. Hope this helps!

Comment: Most laptops from the last decade don't depend on the CMOS battery to store the password, and in many cases the battery cannot simply be changed (they're soldiered on the motherboard).  Have you confirmed that the user's mentioned model even has a CMOS battery they can change?  Can you provide a source?